# How can I perform SVD on a plain Apache Spark Matrix?

Tags: scala, matrix, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Trying to figure out how I can perform further operations on an Apache Spark Matrix. I've created a simple `RowMatrix` and then I have created a covariance matrix from that. However looking at the examples/docs not sure what to do next. Here's my code so far:

```
  def computeCovarianceMatrix(pixelMatrix: Array[Array[Double]]): Matrix = {
    // parallelize the data into Spark
    val data = SparkService.context.parallelize(pixelMatrix)
    val rows = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s))

    val matrix = new RowMatrix(rows)
    matrix.computeCovariance()
  }
```

What I am hoping to do is something as simple as the following (psuedo-code):

```
val covarianceMatrix = computeCovarianceMatrix(pixelMatrix)
val rows = covarianceMatrix.toArray.map(s => Vectors.dense(s))
val matrix = RowMatrix(rows)
matrix.computeSVD(k)
```

Thanks anyone who can help here :)

Comment: What is the question exactly? Your code is correct

Comment: @JeanLogeart wait really? I thought if I performed `.toArray` it would flatten the Matrix. Wouldn't I need some way to indicate # of rows/columns?